# How can I enable webview background audio play in react native (ios)?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-webview

My app plays my content(usually youtube.com video page) with react-native-webview. I want to make the content still played when my app is in background. Now the app just stop playing sound when it became background.

I enabled capability : 
[image: capability]

This is my react-native-webview code.

```
<WebView
  allowsFullscreenVideo
  source={{uri: this.state.url}}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  mixedContentMode={'always'}
  onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={this._deepLinkGuard}
/>
```

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I'm trying to solve the same issue.